# Can't provide redux for webpack/typescript/react - error -> TS2769: No overload matches this call

Tags: typescript, webpack, react-redux

[This one is my entry-point and problem site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Ihc.png)

[Error which i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxpuB.png)

[Here is code on git](https://github.com/MagamedRus/companyChat)

Error in text:

[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\muham\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Учёба\PetProjectChat\src\index.tsx(9,3)
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type '{ store: Store<CombinedState<{ user: UserState; }>, AnyAction> & { dispatch: unknown; }; __self: typeof globalThis; __source: { fileName: string; lineNumber: number; columnNumber: number; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attributes &ineNumber: number; columnNumber: number; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attributes & ProviderProps<Action>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and '__self' does not exist in type 'Attributes & ProviderProps<Action>'.

Error site/entry point:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/App';

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import {store} from './store/index'


render (
    <Provider store={store} >
     <App />,
    </Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Store:

```
import { rootReducer } from "./reducers";

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import {
  applyMiddleware,
  createStore,
} from "redux";


export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```